# Access docker container in interactive shell using Golang

Tags: linux, docker, go, docker-compose, terminal

I am trying to access interactive shell of a running docker container using Golang.
Here is what I tried.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    prg := "docker"

    arg1 := "exec"
    arg2 := "-ti"
    arg3 := "df43f9a0d5c4"
    arg4 := "bash"

    cmd := exec.Command(prg, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    fmt.Printf("[Command] %s\n", cmd.String())
    log.Printf("Running command and waiting for it to finish...")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Command finished with error %s\n", cmd.String())
```

}

AND here is output with error:

```
> [Command] /usr/bin/docker exec -ti df43f9a0d5c4 bash 2022/07/28
> 19:21:02 Running command and waiting for it to finish... the input
> device is not a TTY 2022/07/28 19:21:02 exit status 1 exit status 1
```

> `Note: Interactive shell of running docker container works fine when executing this command directly on the shell`

Comment: What's your eventual goal with this?  Could you use the `"github.com/docker/docker/client"` API client, instead of trying to shell to `docker exec`?  If Docker weren't involved, how would you perform this task to run some command inside some other process?

Comment: I have some service cmmands that I wanted to invoke while container is running. I have no experience with Docker client and I dont know if we can achieve this task with it. For now, 'cmd.Stdin' (tip from Daniel Farrell) works fine for me. But I will definitely dig into docker client to explore it deeply.

Comment: docker cli is built atop the docker client, so it is full featured and can do what you want.  shelling out to docker will work, it's just not very elegant.  You also will probably want to store the commands to issue to docker somewhere, not just type them at a terminal - so when you stop setting your command stdin to a terminal, also stop using `-t`

Comment: Could you show me an example? I actually want to run some scripts once I am in shell inside a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `-t`, telling `docker exec` to allocate a pseudoterminal for the exec session within the container.

But you're not setting `cmd.Stdin` to anything, so the `cmd.Stdin` is `nil`.  [The documentation says](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd)

> // If Stdin is nil, the process reads from the null device (os.DevNull).

The input isn't a terminal so that's why you get

> the input device is not a TTY

You say

> Note: Interactive shell of running docker container works fine when executing this command directly on the shell

Because when you run it directly in the shell, the standard input *is* a terminal.

Try this:

```
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
```